# I can't position the button inside my image

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want to position the button inside the image, and make it stay in its position when I switch to mobile mode or change the size of the window.

This is what I want it to look like:

https://prnt.sc/mij0s6

[image]

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.img-responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 180px;
  margin-left: 360px;
}

a.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 1.45em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  border: 0.15em solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffc966;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

a.btn:hover {
  border-color: #7a7a7a;
}

a.btn:active {
  background-color: #999999;
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
  a.btn {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.2em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
   

   

 <h1>De zakelijke VR/AR hardware leverancier van Benelux</h1>
    
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="vrgt.png">
    </div>
    
    <a href="#" class="btn">Meer Info</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a website where you can host that image? That way it will work in the snippet... Actually, you could just move your button inside of the `<div class="img-wrapper">` and I bet it would get closer to what you want.

Comment: its still appearing outside the image,
i dont have one currently

Comment: Use a `background-image` via CSS instead of an `img` tag.

Comment: no image appears when i try doing that

Comment: @Venzo Please refer my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599934/i-cant-position-the-button-inside-my-image/54601359#54601359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I posted prematurely.. pressed the post button by accident)... You had no css for img or H1.. I added some, I also added a max-width for image in both the main css and the reponsive  (media) css.
The code could do with a bit of tweaking but I'd advise you have a look and adapt it to your needs. It's closer to what you want I think!

EDIT: I'd advise you add a few more media queries to accommodate different screen resolutions as absolute positioning can be a bit of a nightmare on differently-sized devices. [Screenfly](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) is a good tool for testing how your code looks on multiple sizes. Using large margin-bottoms measured in pixels (such as 360px) may result in your button not even displaying on a screen, so try to use vertical height (vh) or percentages when measuring height especially. The [calc function] is also very useful [2](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp). Useful css for centering are `margin : 0 auto` or `text-align:center;`

Best of luck, and hope this helps

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

img {
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 80%;
  margin: 10px 12%;
}

img-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width:100%;
  
}

nav ul li {
  min-width:18%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*.img-responsive {
  /* margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 360px;
}*/

a.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 1.45em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  border: 0.15em solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffc966;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

a.btn:hover {
  border-color: #7a7a7a;
}

a.btn:active {
  background-color: #999999;
}

@media all and (max-width:30em) {
  img {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
  a.btn {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.2em auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>De zakelijke VR/AR hardware leverancier van Benelux</h1>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://gilsig.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/12391435_192385974441516_971157875868647436_n.jpg-North-Shore-Mountains-Dec-2015.jpg">
</div>

<a href="#" class="btn">Meer Info</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button's position should be **absolute** relative to it's first parent element.

```
a.btn 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

a.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 0.2em 1.45em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  border: 0.15em solid #CCCCCC;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #ffc966;
  text-align: center;
}

a.btn:hover {
  border-color: #7a7a7a;
}

a.btn:active {
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre_wide.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="1000" height="300">
</div>
<a href="#" class="btn">Meer Info</a>
```

Comment: you should put a.btn inside .img-wrapper div

Comment: @MladenSkrbic Yes, you are right. I have originally done that way but as user "Venzo" has <a> outside .img-wrapper div, I have answered that way.

Comment: @MladenSkrbic I have tried both way and that looks same to me. Just want to know what would be the difference if we put <a> inside  and outside of .img-wrapper div? can you please let me know?

Comment: .img-wrapper is positioned relative, when u position element absolutly that is inside .img-wrapper it will be positioned relativly to (0,0) coordinate of that div. The reason why it is same in this case is because (0,0) of div is same as (0,0) coordinate of body. If you want see difference you should put div with some height above .img-wrapper